# Why would this php not work but would work this way?

Tags: php

```
if ($sess_uid == $WallID)
{
//
}
else
{
Run Action
}
```

Works
But

```
if (!$sess_uid == $WallID)
{
Run Action
}
```

Wont work. Why is this? I want the code to fire off if both Ids don't match.

Comment: Any particular reason why this is community wiki?

Comment: I checked it thinking it would let me use Wiki Mark up. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
if (!$sess_uid == $WallID)
{
    Run Action
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
if ( (!$sess_uid) == ($WallID))
{
    Run Action
}
```

While you want:

```
if (!($sess_uid == $WallID))
{
    Run Action
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes scene to me.

Comment: Cool. At long last, one of my answers finally made a scene! XD

Answer (score 5):

`!` is having higher [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `==`.

`!a==b` is treated as `(!a) == b`

What you need is `!(a==b)` which is same as `a != b`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the unary operator ! which only operates on the value $sess_uid.  So you are negating the value of $sess_uid.
What you are probably looking for is to use != instead.

`if (!$sess_uid != $WallID){
Run Action
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$sess_uid == $WallID) don't equals if ($sess_uid !== $WallID)
```